# How to add a callback to an activity that's created in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment with a button that calls the following method when it is clicked/pressed:

```
public void onClick() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyNewActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent)
}
```

However, I want to pass a callback method to `MyNewActivity` that is called inside the activity's `onDestroy` method. I need the callback method to call my fragment's `finish()` method.

I tried using static variables and it worked but that seems like a bad design. What's the best way to do this? If not through a callback method, what's a better approach?

Comment: try `startActivityForResult()` for your purpose instead of this callback mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult()` as proposed in comments.

Use below code:

Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1353;

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                                       @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                                       @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        v.findViewById(R.id.btn_start).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hooray! Fragment got result from activity!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Second Activity:

```java
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_finish).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```